# php get value from array which stored in assoc array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Example:

```
$arraytest = array(
key => array("test"),
key2 => value2,
key3 => value3);

foreach ($arraytest as $key=>$val) {
echo $key. "=" .$val. "<br>";
}
```

Result:

```
key=Array
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

So, how can i get value which stored in `$arraytest[0]`? I need to use `foreach` in `foreach` for get

```
key=test
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, how can i get value which stored in `$arraytest[0]`?

Simply use `$arraytest[0]`.  The Array *is* the value of `$arraytest[0]`.  When you convert it to a string, it will just say "Array".

If instead, you want to iterate on that array, you already know how to do that.

```
foreach ($arraytest[0] as $key => $val) {
  echo $key, '=', $val, '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: In this case i get error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: @qqqdddqqq Well yeah, if `0` isn't your key, that will happen.  Change it to `'key'` I guess.  http://codepad.org/TrnXJWcA

Answer (score 0):

The child has also array so you can't echo directly it. Check by `is_array()`. Example:

```
$arraytest = array(
    'key' => array("test"),
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3'
);

foreach ($arraytest as $key=>$val) {
    echo (is_array($val)) ? $key. "=" .$val[0]. "<br>" : $key. "=" .$val. "<br>";
}
```

**Output:**

```
key=test
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you don't mind, can you add some explanation to your code?

Comment: Your array is `$arraytest`. It  contains another array by index `key` (`'key' => array("test")`). You can not directly echo it, because it is not a string, int .... So you should check array by `is_array()`. If it is array then print it's first index. Here the value of `array("test")` is test that is first index.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be that you check if the item is array, traverse through it

```
foreach ($arraytest as $key=>$val) {
    if ( is_array(@val))
    {
        foreach ($val as $k =>$v) {
          echo $k. "=" .$v. "<br>";
        }
    }
    else
        echo $key. "=" .$val. "<br>";
}
```

But this goes only one level inside, you can use Recursive algorithm to go unpredictable numbers of level inside

Answer (score 0):

Here is the recursive function to traverse any array and print its values:

```php
function valuePrint($mixed, $keyStr = '')
{
    if(is_array($mixed)) {
        foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) {
            valuePrint($value, $keyStr . $key . '=>');  // Recursive call
        }
    } else {
        echo $keyStr . $mixed . "\n"; // For html output use '<br/>' instead of "\n"
    }
}
```

Example for calling the function:

```php
$arraytest = array(
    'key'  => array('test'),
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3',
);

valuePrint($arraytest);
```

Result of the call will be:

```
key=>0=>test
key2=>value2
key3=>value3
```

The key `0` of the inner array is also displayed, because it is also a key. I preferred `=>` instead of `=` for the output.